# How to get around using a listview in a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a list of items loaded.

What i want to do with the items is load them into a list in a widget.
But i know list widgets are only supported on 3.0 and above.

So what would be the work-around to get this done?

EDIT:

Maybe add a textview each time a item is loaded...and load the text views into a scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to support scrolling on a stock home screen before 3.0. Widgets use the RemoteViews framework, which on Android 2.x only supports AbsoluteLayout, AnalogClock, Button, Chronometer, FrameLayout, ImageButton, ImageView, LinearLayout, ProgressBar, RelativeLayout, TextView, and ViewFlipper. The only way you could make something at all list-like, is to have up and down buttons for scrolling between items (note: this could only work for complete clicks--you couldn't have it scroll while holding down the button, for example).

Comment: Have you seen commonsware example....  https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem/WidgetProvider.java

Comment: That example will only work on Android 3.0 ("Sample of Android 3.0 app widget with ListView"), which supports more RemoteViews

Comment: So could you give me an example of your suggestion. With some code or a tutorial?

Comment: http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3837531/Handling-User-Interaction-with-Android-App-Widgets.htm